# I think some upvotes and downvotes are biased

Tags: discussion

What I am trying to say, is in the title. Here, **I am not going to speak "about me" or "to me"**, but when you look at questions such as [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40207/name-of-the-food-in-the-picture-in-japanese-and-i-cant-identify-it-in-english), you could very likely think twice.

I actually tried to give the same answer as that of Broccoli. But then I found David's answer was more specific, even with the picture of the baking tool, which even has a stick hole on it. Then I think David's answer is better so I withdrew. But see, I know Broccoli is very popular here, and apparently David's reputation has impact on the number of upvotes. Isn't this unfair? Personally I would not mind if anyone downvotes me to around 100, but you know the criteria should be here somehow very twisted.

Comment: Dont' be confused with this [link](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40287/translation-of-a-sentence-%e7%a7%81%e3%81%af%e3%81%a9%e3%82%8c%e7%a8%8b%e3%81%ae%e4%ba%ba%e9%96%93), which I got 3 downvotes. But man, what I am trying to say here is what I've been thinking for a long time.

Comment: Thank you for speaking out -- for pointing out the obvious. I noticed the pattern within a few days after i started posting here in Jp.SE.  ___________________  There should be a way to compare different forums, (quantify the cliquish-ness of each forum) -- to see if the same ppl are always (or automatically) UpVoting and/or DownVoting the same Posters.

Comment: I think the best site with the least bias I know so far is "philosophy". There unless you don't troll, they ( I mean most of the participants ) judge quite fairly and I like that site.

Comment: One possibility is a weekly msg to the possible offenders. ---e.g.--- You are receiving this msg because SE-VotingSurveyBot has determined that your weekly combined [knee-jerk-voting-Q] (aka BVQ or Biased Voting Quotient) is above xxx -- Your B+VQ (for UpVotes) is yyy which is 5th worst in the site, and your B-VQ (for DownVotes) is zzz which is 3rd worst in the site. Here is a graph of your BVQs in the past year shown along with the average scores in this site. __________ The ultimate goal of such a measure would be to prevent a snowballing build-up of bias, leading to bullying, hazing, etc.

Comment: Well, then if you can check my profile, you see the number of upvotes in other sites are overwhelmingly high. I am not downvoting without reasons ( whenever I DV, I add the reason. ). So, as well as I downvote, people here can give downvotes to me as many as they please. hm.

Comment: It's not a big secret that voting on any SE is nothing but a joke. It doesn't work as it has been designed and hoped for. Don't take votes seriously. But remember, there are more blind upvotes than blind downvotes, which is good for any user on Stack Exchange.

Comment: But I think there are "reasons" why that kind "phoenomenon" can occure. In the comparison with English, Japanese is notoriously hard, even native Japanese speakers make mistakes or do not know the details ( including me ) and whereas there are ample amount of materlas available in the market literally around the glove for English, there are few for JLLs for Japanese. And IMO, I think **this** could drive JLLs pick "sweet sounding" answers especially considering this site is run by Americans.

Comment: But there are many good questions, you know, few days ago somebody asked about the use of the particle ”に”, which when used as the intransitive it makes the whole sentence as if it is passive ( thought not passive ( I think )). Naruto answered so I withdrew, and made upvote on his, well, granted, anyhow, there is a long way ahead for JLLs before they can ask such kind of high level questions, so I kind of "understand".

Comment: `In the comparison with English, Japanese is notoriously hard` Japanese might be notoriously hard *for European language speakers* but *not* for everyone in the glo**b**e. 日本語が印欧語族と離れているから、多くの印欧語話者にとって難しいだけです。逆に韓国語話者は日本語をあっという間にマスターします。日本人にとって韓国語がマスターしやすく印欧語がマスターしにくいのと同じです。全人類にとって「英語が簡単で日本語が難しい」というわけではありません。ケンタロウさんだって何十年も英語やってていまだにそれじゃないですか。`even native Japanese speakers make mistakes or do not know the details` -> 英語やその他の言語についても同じことが言えます。英語・ドイツ語・その他言語母語話者も、母国語でしょっちゅう間違えますし、一般人に文法を聞いたら「自然な言い方はわかるけど、文法の説明はできない」と言います。母国語の文法に疎いのは日本人だけではありません。

Comment: Why are you following me always. I am now bothered by running a company to make marriage with my girl....and then you should not talk to me as you can see above there seem to be others who feel like me. Talk to them. For instance, Rathony dares to say voting on SEs is nothing but a joke. I don't particularly have any problem votinmg on SEs but he seems to have emotional something on it.

Comment: But you know, do we have as same amount of resources as English when we try to learn, for ex, Polish. Actually, there is virtually nothing. I know someone in Poland and I went there, and my friend speaks Polish perfectly ( according to her, she makes mistakes sometimes **yet** ). Since I know little bit about Russian, I can see some kind of familiarity between them but the scarcity of resources, especially solid ones, would have impact on the learner's "access" to the language imo.

Comment: So by your saying Koreans master faster than Europeans, you are admitting that Europeans are having the disadvantage on learning our mother tongue. What does it make difference..........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

（私は自信がなかったので、どちらの回答にもvoteしていません。以下の回答は今調べたことです。）

「ワッフルドッグ」と「waffle dog」で画像検索するとわかりますが、表面に格子状の模様があり、細長くて、中に具材が入っている、あのような食べ物は、間違いなく特異的に「ワッフルドッグ」と呼ばれています。

上記の画像検索では、「ワッフルドッグ」には棒があるものとないものが混在しています。また、普通のワッフル（いわゆる「ベルギーワッフル」）は甘いものが主流でしょうけど、「ワッフルドッグ」と呼ばれているものが甘いとは限りません。というか甘くないものが主流のようです。Kentaro Tomonoさんの「棒があるからワッフルドッグではない」という指摘と、「甘くなさそうだからワッフルドッグではない」という指摘は、私が数分調べた限りいずれも正しくないと思います。棒があって甘くなくてワッフルドッグと呼ばれているものは、ちょっと探せばいくらでも見つかります。

つまりDavid Sさんの回答とbroccoli forestさんの回答はどちらも何ら間違っていないと思います。ただし、「どちらが **specific** な回答か」という観点なら、broccoli forestさんの回答の方がspecificと言えるのではないでしょうか。あの食べ物を見たときの外見上の最大の特徴は、やはりあの「格子模様」の部分ですし、broccoli forestさんの回答はその部分をちゃんと言い当てています。日本語で「アメリカンドッグ」と「ワッフルドッグ」の画像を検索結果を見比べたら、おそらくほぼすべての人が「質問の画像は、ワッフルドッグに近い」と考えるのではないでしょうか。

---

というわけで、本当に "upvotes and downvotes are biased" だと主張したいのであれば、せめて別の例を挙げてください。名前だけ見て回答を読まずに投票するようなバイアスは理論上は存在しうると思いますが、問題となるほどそのような行動が多いとは思いません。

Comment: `別の例を挙げてください。・・・問題となるほどそのような行動が多いとは思いません` そうですね。けんたろうさんは、ブロッコリさんが very popular だっておっしゃるけど、こういう例もありますし、 http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40188/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86-used-right-before-comma-what-does-this-mean-and-how-is-it-grammatically-po/40200#40200　（ブロッコリさんは1点で、他の人にはもっと点数が入っている）「ブロッコリさんだから、内容に関わらず、ほかの新しいユーザーよりも優先してUVする」というような人は特にいないように思いますね。。。

Comment: ワッフル（チーズ入り）を棒付きで食べる人は私の無駄なｗ42年人生で一度たりともないのですが・・・。が、DavidSさんのあの「型」は「まさにそれ」じゃないですかね。

Comment: I'll search for another examples. Please wait a second.

Comment: えっだからワッフルドッグの方が甘くないでしょ。プランプランのチーズワッフルに棒なんかつけて何になんの？ｗ。

Comment: Okay I will take your answer as the nicest coz I could not find another examples.. **However**, if people continue to insist Broccolli's answer is greater, then I will literally burn my house and neighborhood. haha.

Comment: ここで正しいワッフルの食べ方についてとことん議論するのは全く本題ではないので続けません。が、要するに、みんな個々の価値観や知識に基づいて回答内容を吟味してvoteしているのです。自分の意見と違うvoteを見て、バイアスだ陰謀だ談合だといった解釈に飛びつかないで頂けると幸いです。

Comment: まあ、あの写真（棒付き）にチーズが入っている可能性は低い、ということは同意します。ただここは「最も近い調理器具の写真を探して貼った人が優勝」というルールのサイトではないですし、その調理器具の写真がある[元サイトに「アメリカンドッグ」とは書いてありません](https://m.alibaba.com/guide/shop/smart-planet-cdm1-new-corn-dog-maker-kitchen-and-housewares_30137749.html?spm=a2706.8168337.0.0.OfbypG)。「最もspecificな日本語の単語を挙げた」のはbroccoliさんです。

Comment: `その調理器具の写真がある‌​元サイトに「アメリカンドッグ」とは書いて‌​ありません` 私が開いたところ、Corn Dog Makerとは書いてあるようなのですが。。。@Kentaro `their criteria which answer is "correct" is not based on "which is right" but "who you prefer more` なんでそういう論理になるかわかんないですが。。。ところでもうそろそろ Broccoli 正しくつづりましょうよ。。

Comment: @chocolate ええ、なので写真自体は正確でも「それを日本語でどう呼ぶか」の根拠になるような写真ではない、ということです。 Kentaro Tomono さんの基準では、ズバリの名称を挙げている回答よりもズバリの写真を貼っている回答の方が遥かに価値が高いのかもしれませんが、ここJapanese "Language"のサイトですし、聞かれているのも「名称」ですし。

Comment: @naruto Democracyの象徴っていってもよいでしょう。多少バイアスあったとしても（別にあると言ってないですけど）「みんなの声」にはなるので、自分が「これは納得いかん！」っていうのも自分のバイアスじゃないですか。。。